# Why is the function $f(x,y) = 1_{\{x>y\}}$ not in $L^\infty([0,T],L^\infty([0,T]))$

Tags: functional-analysis

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18349), it was stated that the function $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x>y\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$ is not in $L^\infty([0,T],L^\infty([0,T]))$. Why is that so? If I fix any $x$, don't we have $\| f(x,\cdot)\|_\infty \le 1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that for each $x$, $f(x,\cdot)$ is a bounded function of $y$. However $x \mapsto f(x,\cdot)$ is not measurable into $L^\infty([0,T])$ and so $f \not \in L^\infty([0,T],L^\infty([0,T]))$.

To see this, fix a non-measurable subset $A$ of $[0,T]$. Then $f(A) = \{1_{\{\cdot \leq x\}}: x \in A\}$. It is easy to see that any two distinct elements of $f(A)$ are at distance $1$ apart in $L^\infty([0,T])$ and hence the only convergent sequences in $f(A)$ are eventually constant. Hence $f(A)$ is closed and in particular is Borel measurable in $L^\infty([0,T])$. But then $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$ is non-measurable and so $f$ cannot be measurable.